# Can I install Ubuntu One server on my private cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one

So Ubuntu One seems feature rich, and looks like a serious alternative to some of the other "host your own" file syncing software out there (I've tried iFolder and Sparkleshare, but for different reasons, they're not suitable).

Is there any concept of taking Ubuntu One, and hosting it privately on my own server, and then using the clients to connect to my server? Or am I missing the point?

Any answers, even a "you don't want Ubuntu One, you want (insert name of Ubuntu alternative)" is fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, the server-side part of Ubuntu one is not available (and is even closed-source).

I recommend http://owncloud.org/

It is totally open-source, you can install it everywhere, android/iOs apps compatible, all the common protocols are supported.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you. I had looked at owncloud, but didn't want to attempt it until I'd exhausted all reasonable options. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One is more like Dropbox; it's not a personal cloud. There are a number of services available for personal cloud, though:

- OwnCloud, as mentioned
- Seafile
- [Pydio, formerly AjaXplorer](http://pyd.io/)
- [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/)

You could also consider BitTorrent Sync as well. Each of them has their own strengths and weaknesses; I'm currently trying all of them, actually, to see which fits my needs best.

Note: left out some links because I'm new here :( - Google should help you find them.